# Check if spacebar is pressed inside a NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, notifications, nstextview

I have a NSTextView where I need to check when a specific button is pressed. Using ModifierKeyFlags I can check if buttons like shift and control is pressed, but I need to check if SPACE is pressed. Therefore, I cannot use the ModifierFlags (cause it can check some buttons, excluding the spacebar)

So I need a check, that notifies me everytime I press the spacebar in the textfield in my application. Any thoughts? I think it needs to be something like this:

```
if(spacebar is pressed) {
        Dlog(@"give me a notification");
}
```

Comment: NSTextView or NSTextField?  Your title says NSTextView.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is an NSTextView :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSText's delegate.

```
-(void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //Check if it has added a spacebar
}
```

Comment: thanks, this gets me a step further, do you also know how to check if the spacebar is pressed? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'll try fix something up.  But what I have right now is to save a "backup" of the previous string, and then compare it to the new string and see if there's more space bars in the new string.  Though another plausible way of doing this is to just subclass NSTextView and use `-(void)keydown:(NSEvent *)event`, though I'm not sure if that works though.